# No bounty link on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, bounties

I can't find a "start a bounty" link on my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758987/calculate-the-score-only-based-on-the-documents-have-more-occurance-of-term-in-lu). Is this a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question must be at least two days old before you can set a bounty. (It is just 45min old, however).

See also the [bounty faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work):

> **How do I start a bounty? When can I start a bounty?**
>
> A bounty can be started on a question two days after the question was asked.
>
> To start a bounty, click on the "start a bounty" link at the bottom of an eligible question. The bounty panel will open. Use the slider to allocate the bounty amount -- anywhere between 50 and 500 reputation, in 50 point increments.
>
> You must have at least 100 reputation to start a bounty, and at least as much reputation as the bounty amount.
>
> The bounty award will be subtracted from your reputation when the bounty is started, not when it is awarded.

Comment: @Tobias, two days!!!!!!.. i thought whole concept of bounty is to get a fast & best answer... i didnt get any replies for my question.. and the problem i am facing is critical. i need some quick answers... i am willing to offer my 1000 reputation....  its bad i have to wait for 2 days.....

Comment: @jeff, is this 2 days time really required..  because some problems are needed quick response.. like mine..

Comment: @Ramesh Vel: you *can* add a comment on your question promising that, but it is generally frowned upon and edited out...

Comment: @Ramesh - your question is only an hour old (as of this writing) and quite long, you can't expect an immediate answer for what appears to be a complicated problem.

Comment: @Ramesh Vel: see, there is already a [first answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758987/calculate-the-score-only-based-on-the-documents-have-more-occurance-of-term-in-lu/3759583#3759583). You can't expect superfast answers to critical and complicated questions, however (seconding @ChrisF)

Comment: @Chris,@Tobias, yes its a quite big question... i just wanted the question to get more attention.. thats all... anyway i got an answer... :)

Comment: @Ramesh, bounties have nothing to do with getting the "fast & best answer." The bounty process only promises you that a question will be featured. Ideally, the extra rep and the increased visibility will lead to better answers over the 7-day bounty period, but this is not guaranteed.